# How to add tags to a file directory listing in c

Tags: c, bash, list, system-calls, ls

While i understand how to list out the files in your current directory in C i was wondering if it was possible and if so how could you add more information to this listing? For example if i wanted to produce the same results as a command in linux such as `ls -alU --time-style=long-iso` instead of just the files below how could this be done? Would various syscalls be used?

**Current Output**

```
.
..
.git
README.md
lsdir
lsdir.c
```

**Desired Output**

```
total 13
drwx--S--- 3 bh636683 colord  512 2019-03-31 20:55 .
drwx--S--- 8 bh636683 colord  512 2019-03-31 20:43 ..
drwx--S--- 8 bh636683 colord  512 2019-03-31 20:47 .git
-rw------- 1 bh636683 colord   14 2019-03-31 20:47 README.md
-rwx------ 1 bh636683 colord 7296 2019-03-31 20:55 lsdir
-rw------- 1 bh636683 colord  343 2019-03-31 20:55 lsdir.c
```

**CODE SO FAR**

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main (void)
{
  DIR *dp;
  struct dirent *ep;     
  dp = opendir ("./");

  if (dp != NULL)
  {
    while (ep = readdir (dp))
      puts (ep->d_name);

    (void) closedir (dp);
  }
  else
    perror ("Couldn't open the directory");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read up on functions like `stat(2)` and `getpwuid(3)`.

Comment: @BretHasel [Implementing the ls -al command in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554150/implementing-the-ls-al-command-in-c).

Comment: Thank you that helped and got the sizes to be printed out correctly now but is it possible to do the same with the permissions and date/time as well?